# KSQL - calculate distance from 2 messages using GEO_DISTANCE

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I've a kafka topic and each message in the topic has lat/lon and event timestamp. Created a stream referring to topic and would like to calculate distance between 2 point using geo_distance .
example

```
GpsDateTime            lat              lon
2016-11-30 22:38:36,    32.685757,  -96.735942
2016-11-30 22:39:07,    32.687347,  -96.732841
2016-11-30 22:39:37,    32.68805,   -96.729726
```

I would like to create a new stream on the above stream and enrich it with distance.

```
GpsDateTime            lat              lon          Distance
2016-11-30 22:38:36,    32.685757,  -96.735942        0
2016-11-30 22:39:07,    32.687347,  -96.732841        0.340
2016-11-30 22:39:37,    32.68805,   -96.729726        0.302
```

Is it possible to achieve desired results using KSQL ? Or how to refer previous message while processing new message?

Comment: I know you can do time windows, so if events are coming in by 30 seconds, you can group two messages together like that, but I'm not sure if you can reference other rows in KSQL, and this might require Kafka Streams

Comment: how it can be achieved in Kafka steaming or spark streaming?  Do we have a method/functions to refer to previous row ?

Comment: I'm not super familiar with either, but both tools allow you to access a batch of records within a time window. If you can iterate/index those elements individually in order of arrival time, I'm not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, do these readings come from some sort of device? If so do you have a unique ID (UUID) for them? I would put that into your stream, so it would like like `UUID, GpsDateTime, lat, lon`.

You will need to create a fairly basic Kafka Streams app. Within this app you will be storing the most recent reading from your stream into a StoreBuilder. Then when a new message is received from Kafka you will retrieve this latest value, do your computation and then store the new lat,long values into the StoreBuilder.

Of course I'm not clear if you are wanting to only *ever* have one lat,long value and all your subsequent values are computed from the 1st reading. Or if you want to have a rolling compute where you are always comparing the distance between the last and current reading.

Anyway, you can see this code in practice at: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.0.0-post/src/test/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/StateStoresInTheDSLIntegrationTest.java

This example is a word count example, but can be quickly converted for your use case.

The static final class WordCountTransformerSupplier (line 78) would become your LatLongDistanceComputation.

You would create the StoreBuilder (line 154) with proper types (whatever you are storing your lat/lon as).

Line 165 is where the item is actually being read from the stream of values flowing in.

And of course you need to edit the inputTopic and outputTopic (line 66-67) amongst a few other things.

Comment: Thanks ... i got the design how should it work from your message...Let me try and see how its works with millions of messages .

Comment: A Kafka Streams app is scalable as it's built on top of Kafka's core Producer/Consumer APIs. You can add additional nodes to your process if you have millions of messages to compute on. Kafka will see these new nodes and immediately begin to Parallelise workloads to them. Please see: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html#parallelism-model