# How to write a KSQL query to distint region id for particular user

Tags: ksqldb

Hi I have created a following stream with following values,

"account_id VARCHAR, user_id VARCHAR, src_ip VARCHAR, country_code VARCHAR, message VARCHAR"

Now I can create a table with only specific account_id matched field within given tumbling window as below,

```
CREATE TABLE  221_console_failure AS \
      SELECT user_id, country_code \ 
      FROM my_stream \
      WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 600 SECONDS) \
      WHERE account_id = '4894833322'
```

Is there any way to find if same user logged in from different country code value within 10 min

My country_code field contains value like IN, US, SG etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your use case you can use HISTOGRAM for as a work around until KSQL provides DISTINCT function.

> HISTOGRAM(col1) (input type:STREAM/TABLE): Return a map containing the distinct String values of col1 mapped to the number of times each one occurs for the given window. This version limits the number of distinct values which can be counted to 1000, beyond which any additional entries are ignored.

```
CREATE TABLE 221_console_failure AS \
      SELECT user_id, \
      HISTOGRAM(country_code) as region, count(*) 
      FROM my_stream \
      WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 600 SECONDS) \
      WHERE user_account_id = '4894833322' \
                    GROUP BY user_account_id;
```

```
Output at consumer: b'{"USER_ID":"4894833322","REGION":{"SG":2,"IN":3},"KSQL_COL_2":5}'
```

Now you can just check for the map length > 1 at REGION as it collects distinct values.

You can also try using scalar function `GEO_DISTANCE(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, unit)` if you have longitude and latitude.
[KSQL - calculate distance from 2 messages using GEO_DISTANCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52267154/ksql-calculate-distance-from-2-messages-using-geo-distance)

Answer (score 0):

KSQL doesn't yet support `COUNT(DISTINCT)`, which is what you need here, so as to be able to run this:

```
SELECT USER_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT COUNTRY_CODE) \
  FROM USER_EVENTS WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 10 MINUTES) \
GROUP BY USER_ID \
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT COUNTRY_CODE) > 1;
```

Please feel free to vote/comment on https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/506 if this feature would be useful for you.

Comment: DISTINCT keyword itself is not available right? so your above example query will also not work correct? I tried and it says "no viable alternative at input 'COUNT(DISTINCT'  "

Comment: Correct. It is not available yet. The example I gave is the SQL that you *would* need to run *if* KSQL did support it.